# MS Access nested continuous form?

Tags: ms-access

I'm a volunteer in a non-profit organization.
I built a MS Access db we use during emergencies.

I can't understand how to show a continuous form, where each element can have multiple subelements.

Hope you can understand with these few informations:

Table events:

```
+-------------+---------+
| event_id    | Counter |
+-------------+---------+
| description | Text    |
+-------------+---------+
| code_a      | Text    |  
+-------------+---------+
| code_b      | Text    |
+-------------+---------+
```

Table rescues:

```
+-------------+---------+
| id_rescue   | Counter |
+-------------+---------+
| id_event    | Text    |
+-------------+---------+
| time_1      | Text    |  
+-------------+---------+
| time_2      | Text    |
+-------------+---------+
```

I have to create a form to view all events, and for all events all rescues.
Each event can have from 0 to n rescues.

Something like this:

```
event_id        description     code_a  code_b          event_id rescue_id  ambulance_name  time_1  time_2  time_3  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               description_1   code_1  detail_1    |   1        12         alpha          00:10    00:16   00:27
                                                    |   1        14         bravo          00:10    00:16   00:27
                                                    |   1        16         charlie        00:10    00:16   00:27
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2               description_2   code_2  detail_2    |   2        18         delta          00:10    00:16   00:27
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3               description_3   code_3  detail_3    |   3        22         yankee         00:10    00:16   00:27
                                                    |   3        14         zulu           00:10    00:16   00:27
                                                    |   3        76         golf           00:10    00:16   00:27
                                                    |   3        35         romeo          00:10    00:16   00:27
                                                    |   3        96         victor         00:10    00:16   00:27
                                                    |   3        36         sierra         00:10    00:16   00:27
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can download a **very simplified** ms Access db with tables and relationships here: http://www.criferrara.it/download/Test_DB.accdb

Many thanks for your help.

Francesco

Answer (score 1):

Its been long, but I got a solution to this problem and I could use it. 
Microsoft Access 2013 32 bit, Windows 10 x64.

My solution is to create desired result using Grouping Sorting on a report. And use the report as subreport to another form if needed.Open the form as usual.

If you want to open the report instead directly not a subreport of a form, you can use acViewReport mode which is different from acViewPreview.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptPackingStation", acViewReport
```

Comment: Yes, a report with `acViewReport` is the best solution to this sort of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Despite Access telling you that you can't have a continuous main form and continuous sub form , you actually CAN. Just ignore the warning and then reset the view of the main form.

Normally you would put the Sub form in the footer of the main form, however if the layout suits you better you could put two continuous forms next to each other as sub forms within a holding mainform.

Alternatively if you only want to view the items not edit them you could replicate your desired layout using a report view with the right hand data on a sub report.

Edit - I've adjusted your sample to show two simple methods of getting sub forms to work one as a footer, one a a separate form.
[Edited Sample DB](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=65416&stc=1&d=1487943021)

Comment: I cannot ignore the warning. View mode is reset to data view when I hit "ok". I updated the ms access file in my main post with a main form and 2 subforms.
Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I can't put second subfrom in primary subform's footer because in this case I show "event" details only clicking on single event.
form should be as described in the answer.

Comment: Well when I said ignore - I really meant just click ok. I assumed your main form was a continuous form not a datasheet. You can't easily embed multiple datasheet forms. There is a method shown here https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=225559

Comment: Maybe there was a mistake in uploaded file, now I updated it.
 As you can see, I cannot set "sub_events" form as "continue". When Access prompts the error, it automatically reset form type to "single form"

Comment: I'm not at home, I'll will check it monday

Comment: can't download your edited sample DB. it says : "Invalid Attachment specified. If you followed a valid link, please notify the administrator"

Comment: Actually the sample is virtually Identical to the screenshots provided by Albert, so if that functionality / layout is not going to work for you, then the report option as described by Albert is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t nest continues forms. However an easy workaround is to simply have a main form and drop in the two continues forms side by side.

In this following screen we have a classic “check” disbursement (like accounting packages). On the left we have a continues form of donation amounts, and on the right we distribute the donation amount to several accounts.

[image]

In the left “master” form (which is now a subform), in the on current event, you need to place the following command to make the child on the right side to follow this form.

```
me.Parent.Child1.Requery
me.Parent.Child2.Requery.
```

So side by side forms don’t “automatic” follow – you need the above to “update” the right side form as you move in the left side form.

You can still (and should) use the link child/master settings for the left form.

Eg something like this:

```
linkChildFields      main_id        (whatever is the name of the field in
                                    this sub-form that is used to relate
                                     back to the parent table)
LinkMasterFields    [MasterForm].[form].[ID]
```

In the link child/master settings for child 2 form (right side) you place

```
linkChildFields      main_id        
                    (whatever is the name of the field in this
                     sub-form that is used to relate back to 
                     the parent table)
LinkMasterFields    [leftSideMasterForm].[form].[ID]
                    ("leftmasterForm" is the name of the control you 
                     used to hold the left master form).
```

So while you can’t nest continues forms, you can most certainly place sub forms “side by side” to achieve the same result. And in above you can see I even have conditional formatting that goes "green" to show when the amounts on the right side form = donation amount on the left side.

Comment: I just tried this, but the operator has to see all data at the same time (like in my example: all events with all ambulances)

Comment: Ok, then consider using a report. place the right side continues form (or report) in the detail. You not be able to edit, but you can make the row "clickable" that would launch one row with a sub form to editing the one "record" with sub form values.